# Help needed with converting sentence to predicate logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, logic-translation

Say x represents real numbers and E(x) represent Even numbers and I(x) represents Integers.

How would you convert this sentence to predicate logic?
*No even integers are odd*

Here's my attempt, but I have a feeling it could be wrong 
¬ ∀x ( E(x) ^ I(x) => ¬E(x) )

Comment: NO; $¬∃x ( I(x) \land E(x) \land ¬E(x) )$

Comment: Your formula is equivalent to: $∃x ¬(I(x) ∧ E(x) \to ¬E(x))$ i.e. to $∃x (I(x) ∧ E(x) ∧ E(x))$.

Comment: You could try reinterpret the sentence as "every even integer is non-odd."

Comment: There is no need for the negation symbol before the ∀x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence $\neg \forall x ( (E(x) \land I(x)) \rightarrow \neg E(x) )$ is saying that 'not all even integers are not even' ... which is the same as saying that 'some even integers are even'.

However, 'no even integers are odd' can be understood as 'all even integers are not odd', and so it should be:

$\forall x ( (E(x) \land I(x)) \rightarrow \neg E(x) )$